# Login Via SQLite database does not work

Tags: android, sqlite

I was working on an app that requires a login. No matter what I do, the function always returns 0.

```
public int Login(String username,String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase("Users", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Log.i("Details:",username+password);
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{username, password};
    try
    {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from users WHERE email = '"+username+"' AND password = '"+password+"'",null);

        Log.i("Important2",Integer.toString(c.getCount()));
        if(c.getCount()>0) {
            c.close();
            return 1;
        }
        db.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a snapshot of databse.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of potential problems:-

### Using openOrCreateDatabase

First you are using `openOrCreateDatabase`, which will create a database should the database not exist. In which case the database would not contain the users table. Ultimately resulting in your method returning 0.

### Trapping Errors

Because you are using (`try {...} catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}`) around your code, you may be masking what would otherwise be an error that results in an exception.

So, as an example, if openOrCreateDatabase is used and a database is created, then the exception raised due to the **users** table not existing will be trapped and processing will continue and a return code of 0 will be the result.

However, if you looked at the log then you would see something along the lines of :-

```
01-26 21:34:11.525 1545-1545/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: users
01-26 21:34:11.525 1545-1545/? W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: users (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * from users WHERE email = 'Fred@fred.com' AND password = 'password'
```

### The Obvious

Initially looking at your code, the obvious error would be that the email/username and password do not exist would also result in a 0 being returned.

I would suggest changing the Login method to the following (*noting that code between the `//********`'s would likely certainly be removed when you've ironed out all the creases.* )

```
public int Login(String username,String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String dbname = "Users";
    String tbname = "users";
    String email_column = "email";
    String name_column = "name";
    String password_column = "password";
    String workshops_column = "workshops";
    String dbpath = getActivity().getDatabasePath(dbname).getPath();
    String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            tbname +
            " (" +
            email_column + " TEXT, " +
            name_column + " TEXT, " +
            password_column + " TEXT, " +
            workshops_column + " TEXT" +
            ")";

    Log.i("LOGIN_DBPATH","Database Path=" + dbpath);

    //Open the database, if not then create database and add table
    db = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase(dbname,MODE_PRIVATE,null);

    // Database exists so check that the users table exists
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{"table",tbname};
    String whereclause = "type=? AND tbl_name=?";
    Cursor chkcsr = db.query("sqlite_master",
            null,
            whereclause,
            whereargs,
            null,null,null
    );
    if (chkcsr.getCount() < 1) {
        Log.i("LOGIN_CHKTBL",tbname + " table was not found. Creating table.");
        db.execSQL(crtsql);
        chkcsr.close();
        db.close();
        return 0; // no users so user cannot login
    }
    chkcsr.close();

    Log.i("Details:",username+password);
    //********
    // During development
    Cursor testcsr = db.query(tbname,
            null,null,null,null,null,null
    );
    if (testcsr.getCount() < 1) {
        Log.i("LOGIN_TESTUSRS","The " + tbname + " table is empty.");
    } else {
        while (testcsr.moveToNext()) {
            String test_username = testcsr.getString(testcsr.getColumnIndex(email_column));
            String test_password = testcsr.getString(testcsr.getColumnIndex(password_column));
            if (test_password.equals(password) && test_username.equals(username)) {
                Log.i("LOGIN_TESTUSRS",
                        "MATCH FOUND at row " +
                                String.valueOf(testcsr.getPosition() + 1)
                );
            }
            else {
                Log.i("LOGIN_TESTUSRS",
                        "MISMATCH at row " +
                                String.valueOf(testcsr.getPosition() + 1)
                );
            }
        }
    }
    testcsr.close();
    //********
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{username, password};
    Cursor c = db.query(
            tbname,
            null,
            email_column + "=? AND " + password_column + "=?",
            selectionArgs,
            null,null,null
    );
    int usercount = c.getCount();
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return usercount;
}
```

The above :-

- Creates various variables used throughout.
- Uses the `openOrCreateDatabase` which will either open an existing database or create a new database (as the original did).
- Queries the **sqlite_master** table to see if the **users** tables exists.

  - If not (*cursor's count is < 1*) it creates the **users** table, closes the cursor used for the query, closes the database and returns 0 as it's impossible that any users exists and therefore no-one can login.
  - Otherwise processing continues.
- For problem determination a testing Cursor is created by retrieving all rows from the **users** table.

  - If there are no rows in the table this is then written to the log.
  - Each row is then checked to see if it matches the given username/email and password. The result being written to the log.
  - NOTE this does not return it allows processing to continue.
- Finally your original check (*albeit modified slightly*) for the email/username and password is undertaken.

### Results

#### No Database Exists:-

```
01-27 00:35:00.441 3746-3746/? I/LOGIN_DBPATH: Database Path=/data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:35:00.481 3746-3746/? I/DBPATH_REALLOGIN: /data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:35:00.485 3746-3746/? I/LOGIN_CHKTBL: users table was not found. Creating table.
01-27 00:35:00.485 3746-3748/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 212K, 10% free 6165K/6791K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 3ms
01-27 00:35:00.493 3746-3746/? I/DBPATH_REAL: /data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:35:00.493 3746-3746/? I/DBTBLCOUNT: Rows in the users table is 0
```

#### No Users Exist but database does exist:-

```
01-27 00:37:52.926 3795-3795/? I/LOGIN_DBPATH: Database Path=/data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:37:52.934 3795-3795/? I/DBPATH_REALLOGIN: /data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:37:52.950 3795-3795/? I/Details:: Fred@fred.compassword
01-27 00:37:52.950 3795-3795/? I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: The users table is empty.
01-27 00:37:52.950 3795-3799/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 218K, 10% free 6166K/6791K, paused 11ms+0ms, total 14ms
01-27 00:37:52.950 3795-3795/? I/DBPATH_REAL: /data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:37:52.950 3795-3795/? I/DBTBLCOUNT: Rows in the users table is 0
```

#### users Exists but no matching users :-

```
01-27 00:40:16.733 3852-3852/mjt.fragtest I/LOGIN_DBPATH: Database Path=/data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:40:16.741 3852-3852/mjt.fragtest I/DBPATH_REALLOGIN: /data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:40:16.753 3852-3854/mjt.fragtest D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 215K, 9% free 6159K/6727K, paused 12ms+0ms, total 14ms
01-27 00:40:16.753 3852-3852/mjt.fragtest I/Details:: Fred@fred.compassword
01-27 00:40:16.753 3852-3852/mjt.fragtest I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: The users table is empty.
01-27 00:40:16.753 3852-3852/mjt.fragtest I/DBPATH_REAL: /data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:40:16.753 3852-3852/mjt.fragtest I/DBTBLCOUNT: Rows in the users table is 0
01-27 00:40:16.785 3852-3852/mjt.fragtest I/LOGIN_DBPATH: Database Path=/data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:40:16.785 3852-3852/mjt.fragtest I/DBPATH_REALLOGIN: /data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:40:16.789 3852-3852/mjt.fragtest I/Details:: Fred@fred.compassword
01-27 00:40:16.789 3852-3852/mjt.fragtest I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: Checking Row 1 Username is Fred@fred.com being checked against login username Fred@fred.com Password is not the rightpassword being checked against login password password.
01-27 00:40:16.789 3852-3852/mjt.fragtest I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: MISMATCH at row 1
01-27 00:40:16.789 3852-3852/mjt.fragtest I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: Checking Row 2 Username is Bert@fred.com being checked against login username Fred@fred.com Password is password being checked against login password password.
01-27 00:40:16.789 3852-3852/mjt.fragtest I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: MISMATCH at row 2
```

#### Finally matching user exists :-

```
01-27 00:41:35.200 3897-3897/? I/LOGIN_DBPATH: Database Path=/data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:41:35.216 3897-3897/? I/DBPATH_REALLOGIN: /data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:41:35.228 3897-3899/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 217K, 10% free 6160K/6791K, paused 11ms+11ms, total 24ms
01-27 00:41:35.228 3897-3897/? I/Details:: Fred@fred.compassword
01-27 00:41:35.228 3897-3897/? I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: Checking Row 1 Username is Fred@fred.com being checked against login username Fred@fred.com Password is not the rightpassword being checked against login password password.
01-27 00:41:35.228 3897-3897/? I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: MISMATCH at row 1
01-27 00:41:35.228 3897-3897/? I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: Checking Row 2 Username is Bert@fred.com being checked against login username Fred@fred.com Password is password being checked against login password password.
01-27 00:41:35.228 3897-3897/? I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: MISMATCH at row 2
01-27 00:41:35.232 3897-3897/? I/DBPATH_REAL: /data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:41:35.232 3897-3897/? I/DBTBLCOUNT: Rows in the users table is 2
01-27 00:41:35.236 3897-3897/? I/LOGIN_DBPATH: Database Path=/data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:41:35.236 3897-3897/? I/DBPATH_REALLOGIN: /data/data/mjt.fragtest/databases/Users
01-27 00:41:35.240 3897-3897/? I/Details:: Fred@fred.compassword
01-27 00:41:35.240 3897-3897/? I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: Checking Row 1 Username is Fred@fred.com being checked against login username Fred@fred.com Password is not the rightpassword being checked against login password password.
01-27 00:41:35.240 3897-3897/? I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: MISMATCH at row 1
01-27 00:41:35.240 3897-3897/? I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: Checking Row 2 Username is Bert@fred.com being checked against login username Fred@fred.com Password is password being checked against login password password.
01-27 00:41:35.240 3897-3897/? I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: MISMATCH at row 2
01-27 00:41:35.240 3897-3897/? I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: Checking Row 3 Username is Fred@fred.com being checked against login username Fred@fred.com Password is password being checked against login password password.
01-27 00:41:35.240 3897-3897/? I/LOGIN_TESTUSRS: MATCH FOUND at row 3
```

***Note***
to simplify testing and progressivley add rows to the table, the `Login` method was called twice, hence the length results for the latter two tests.

Answer (score -1):

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from users WHERE email = '"+username+"' AND password = '"+password+"'",null);
```

Issue is in this line at WERE email you are setting equals to username check this line kindly and let me know if this work.
Waiting for your kind response.